# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost in Alamofire.

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

I am a newbie to iOS and uploading image using Alamofire. Here is my code:

```
let image = imageView.image
        let parameters = ["profile_picture" : "pic"]
        let fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)
        let URL2 = try! URLRequest(url: "######", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization" : "######"])

            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 200
            manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        manager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append(fileData!, withName: "profile_picture", fileName: "upfile", mimeType: "image/jpg")


            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, with: URL2 , encodingCompletion: { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON {
                    response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any]{
                        let messageString = JSON["message"] as? String
                        debugPrint(messageString)

                    }else {

                        let alertError = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Image upload error", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alertError.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alertError, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)

            let alertError = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Image upload error", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertError.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertError, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    )
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
2017-11-07 12:54:13.055846+0500 TestApiProject[5972:136877] TIC Read Status [1:0x604000177a00]: 1:57
2017-11-07 12:54:13.057150+0500 TestApiProject[5972:136877] Task <BF98A675-2BCE-4248-A045-EA2D35971EAA>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
2017-11-07 12:54:13.058097+0500 TestApiProject[5972:136879] Task <BF98A675-2BCE-4248-A045-EA2D35971EAA>.<1> finished with error - code: -1005
[Request]: POST http://.....
[Response]: nil
[Data]: 0 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000245e50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://staging.discretelogix.com:5002/api/v1/users/profile-picture, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://staging.discretelogix.com:5002/api/v1/users/profile-picture, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 531734052.362, "Initial Response Time": 531734052.721, "Request Completed Time": 531734053.071, "Serialization Completed Time": 531734053.077, "Latency": 0.359 secs, "Request Duration": 0.710 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.006 secs, "Total Duration": 0.715 secs }
```

I searched regarding this error and things I tried till now are:

- Restarting xcode and simulator. (As it was marked accepted in mostly
  questions)
- Cleaning the project.
- Deleting derived data. (Xcode -> Preferences -> Derived Data)
- Increasing the request timed out parameter value for Alamofire.

But unfortunately, none of the above solved my problem.

In another place, I read about "Keep Alive" parameter in header. And that the default value for Keep alive in iOS is 30sec and needs to increased in my case. But I found nothing related to it in Alamofire. I just found that it belongs to the underlaying URLSession and needs to be updated.

So my questions are:

- How can I use Keep Alive parameter in my Alamofire header? Can I?
- If not then how to update it in URLSession?
- Is there something I need to change in my Alamofire code?
- Is there any other solution to my problem?

I hope I am clear enough with what I need. I am new to iOS and been searching this error since morning. Any help would be much appreciated.

P.s, I am using:

Xcode 9, Swift 3.2, Alamofire 4